# Standalone WSGI servers for production

Tags: rest, wsgi, uwsgi

I've been learning about WSGI for REST APIs in python.  I've got a working setup with Lighttpd+FastCGI.

However this path will be dedicated to serving the API - Static content will be delivered via a Content Delivery network and any web sites can be set up as REST clients to the API.

There are far too many Python WGSI servers.  Seems like besides the one built into Python, every WSGI module, framework, any my dog includes one, and these almost universally comes with a "Use it for development, but you may want to use a proper production quality WSGI stack".

Python Paste looks promising, but is it really stable, and does it duplicate too much of my existing web.py+army-of-modules framework?

My primary criteria is:

- Stability.  I want something I can pretty much configure and not worry about.
- Security.  Don't introduce security holes.
- Performance: Should perform well enough.  I certainly don't want it to be the bottleneck in my implementation, but I see benchmarks showing that WSGI servers handles many hundreds of requests per second so as long as the WSGI server is not abnormally slow I don't expect this to be an issue.

What other aspects of the WSGI server do I need to be concerned about in a high-volume environment?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) used in pretty important production environments, so that would probably be your best choice. I can also do a shameless plug here for [netius](http://netius.hive.pt), which is a Python network library that can be used for the rapid creation of asynchronous non-blocking servers and clients. It has no dependencies, it's cross-platform, and brings some sample netius-powered servers out of the box, namely a production-ready WSGI server. I can't recommend that project for having been used by a lot of people, even though we use it for a mission-critical SaaS service of ours with significant load, but the only advantage to you in particular is that the codebase is small, strictly structured, and extensively commented, so you can easily audit it for security yourself.

Comment: I'll take a look...  But I though WSGI prevents the server from being asynchronous!?

Comment: Well that's just not true, while Python's base library is mainly synchronous based (file IO, etc), there's nothing in WSGI preventing an asynchronous based implementation.

Comment: This article explain how to handle the tricks involved in implementing an asynchronous handling under WSGI. http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html